# How to calculate the voltage value for current from the wall socket using iphone magnetometer values?

Tags: iphone, magnetometer, cmmotionmanager

I want to calculate the current passing in the wall socket using iphone.I am using CMMotionmanagerFramework and i got X,Y,Z values with that values i can calculate the magnetic field across the surroundings by using those values i want to calculate the voltage level of the wall socket. Please provide me the answer.

Comment: You can't calculate voltage from current without having a known resistance.  Ohm's law.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field strength gives you the [electric field strength in volts per meter](http://www.livephysics.com/simulations/electricity-magnetism-sim/electric-current-magnetic-field/), related to the velocity of the electrons. The velocity of the electrons is known as the [drift velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity), and is related to the current. The electric field strength depends on the [charge density in the wire](http://faculty.wwu.edu/vawter/PhysicsNet/Topics/ElectricForce/LineChargeDer.html), which should be a constant you can find for the wire you're using, and the distance from the detector to the wire.

So your magnetic field strength depends on a bunch of constants related to the physical arrangement of your problem and *the current in the wire*. You can derive that using your iPhone's magnetometer, knowledge of its accuracy and some maths. The voltage drop (potential difference) across the outlet is related to the current by the [reactance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance), because you're probably looking at an Alternating Current system so inductances and capacitances play a role, in addition to the resistance.

However you probably don't need to calculate the potential difference, because the electrical utility company will tell you what it is.